# How can I Count an Integer Value from Edittext Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm really new in android programming.

I want to make an application that can count how many numbers you input into an `EditText`, but unfortunately I can't find a method that can do this.

Thanks for helping me, 
best regards.

Comment: are looking for a way to increment count only when integers are entered? Or when submitted a value from eddittext then extract only integers and then count of those integers?

Comment: why don't you google such simple question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i misunderstood question, you can get length of `EditText` content by using `length()` method of String

```
int length=edt.getText().toString().length();
```

Comment: yes, but i wanna count how many numbers I input on 'EditText' , i can't find any method on android

Comment: What do you mean by how many numbers? are you talking about length of edittext?

Answer (score 0):

You can add listner to your EditText.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int lngth = s.length();
   }
   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }
   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Lil long but works

```
int inputNum = edtInputNum.getText().length();
String num = Integer.toString(inputNum);
tvCountNum.setText(num);
```